# How to get all unique email recipients python gmail api

Tags: gmail-api

I want to do a search for all unique email recipients from gmail. But I'm really struggling with API. If I was interacting with a SQL database I would want something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EmailRecipient FROM MyHypotheticalGmailTable;
```

But I'm not sure how to translate this into a gmail API call.

Answer (score 1):

**I suggest you start by taking a look at the Gmail API Quickstart with Python [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python).**

Afterwards you may want to take a look at `threads.list` in order to list all the threads available and then for each one use `threads.get`. Since there is no direct method of retrieving the unique email recipients, you will have to handle this separately from the API calls and filter the results programmatically.

#### Reference

- [Gmail API Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python);
- [Gmail API messages.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list);
- [Gmail API messages.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/get).